# Which method is fast perfomance stand point to load image?

Tags: html, css

I want image in HTML page. I am wondering what way gives best optimization performance stand point. I have two option to load image.

1. Load image directly using image tag inside div of html.
2. Get image to div background using css background.

Comment: Also you can load it via `data:uri` (both within `html` and `css`).

Both images will be loaded by browser and cached. What "optimization" you talking about?

Comment: I am not asking ways to load image. I know bunch of way to do it. I am asking which method takes less time to load among this methods.

Comment: Why would you think there is a difference? Have you found, experimentally, that there is? Have you, for instance, measured how long it takes in one method, then changed the HTML to the other method and found that one much faster? Without clearing the cache in between?

Answer (score 0):

They would be about the same, at least if there was a difference, it would be so small you would never notice it.

Speed of load would mostly depend on the size of the image whether its set to the background in the css or placed directly in the mark-up. I think this is answering your question but it's quite vague...